# Capturing microphone input through HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, web-standards, html5-audio

If I get it right, this will be achieved through the HTML5 JavaScript API `navigator.getUserMedia()` in the future.

As of this date, what browsers support it? Beta, alpha, build from source.. How can I play around with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/web-real-time-communication/documentation

This is the only documentation at the time. Only for a certain browser. No major browser supports it.

Comment: I stumbled upon that page as well. Perhaps it is the only way. I really hope this feature will be released to major browsers soon

Comment: It says they are working on adding it to WebKit, which would mean Chrome, Safari, Rockmelt, and others.

Comment: Also: http://caniuse.com/#audio-api

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has an experimental implementation available in nightly builds.

check out [Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API)

[Obtaining_Builds](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Obtaining_Builds)

Comment: Yep that is great, but as far I understand it is only for modifying the audio when you already have the source